# Which components are non-reusable after a sub-orbital spaceflight with Virgin Galactic?

Tags: reuse, sub-orbital, tourism, virgin-galactic

I wonder which components are non-reusable after a [sub-orbital spaceflight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-orbital_spaceflight) with [Virgin Galactic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Galactic).

What I have found so far:

https://www.virgingalactic.com/learn/ ([mirror](https://archive.vn/V7W90)):

> With the exception of the rocket motor’s fuel and oxidizer, which must be replenished after each flight, SpaceShipTwo is a fully reusable spacecraft.

https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smithsonian-institution/engine-powering-future-civilian-spaceflight-enters-collections-180971493/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201214005348/https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smithsonian-institution/engine-powering-future-civilian-spaceflight-enters-collections-180971493/)):

> RocketMotorTwo is a hybrid rocket motor that combines the simplicity of a solid propellant rocket engine with the controllability of a liquid propellant engine. The motor consists of two main parts—a large tank which stores the liquid oxidizer (nitrous oxide), and the cartridge which stores hydroxyl-terminated polybutadiene (HTPB) solid fuel. This combination, known as the Case/Throat/Nozzle (CTN), the guts of the engine, is the portion of RocketMotorTwo donated to the museum. **It is one of the only non-reusable components of SpaceShipTwo**.

As a result, more specifically I wonder:

1. What are the non-reusable component(s) of SpaceShipTwo aside from the engine's Case/Throat/Nozzle (CTN)?
2. Aside from the SpaceShipTwo's non-reusable components, are there any other non-reusable component(s)?

---

SpaceShipTwo's engine's Case/Throat/Nozzle (CTN):

[image]